# Why is argv[1] printing uppercase characters?

Tags: c, cs50

I converted the second argument, argv[1] to uppercase so I can check for any repeated characters.  I did this by putting everything from argv[1] into a string called "key", then convert everything to uppercase inside "key".  Now everything inside "key" is the same as argv[1] but it's all uppercase.  However, when I print argv[1], that was converted to uppercase too.  I need everything in argv[1] to stay the same.  Does anyone know what I did wrong?
Also just as a note, I'm using "string" from the cs50 library.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const int key_length = 26;
int string_length = 0;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetic characters.\n");
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            string_length += 1;
        }

    }
    if (string_length != key_length)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 3;
    }

    string key = argv[1];                       // converting key letters here
    for (int a = 0; a < strlen(key); a++)
    {
        if (!isupper(key[a]))
        {
            key[a] = toupper(key[a]);
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < strlen(key); l++)
    {
        for (int h = l + 1; h < strlen(key); h++)
        {
            if (key[l] == key[h])
            {
                printf("No duplicates in key: %c\n", key[l]);
                return 4;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string key = argv[1];` does not copy the characters pointed to by `argv[1]` to `key`.

The type `string` is defined to be `char *`, a pointer to a `char`. `argv[1]` is also a pointer to a `char`. `string key = argv[1];` creates a new pointer named `key` and sets it to point to the same place that `argv[1]` points.

Then, when you change the characters pointed to by `key` to uppercase, you are also changing the characters pointed to by `argv[1]`, since they are the same characters.

To work with a copy of the characters, you must make a copy yourself:

```
string key = malloc(strlen(argv[1] + 1); // Allocate space for characters in argument plus null terminator.
if (!key) // Test whether allocation succeeded.
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(key, argv[1]); // Copy characters.
```

Comment: Eric, thank you for answering!  That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why CS50 authors do this horrible thing.

`string` is a simple `char *`.

`string key = argv[1];`

Your problem is the effect of hiding pointers behind typedefs.

`key` references the same memory location as `argv`

You need to alocate memory in `key` corresponding to the length of `argv[1]` (+1 for string terminator):

```
string key = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
/* check if the allocation was OK - I will skip it for the call clarity */
strcpy(key, argv[1]);
```

Comment: Appreciate you answering!

Comment: Yeah, the CS50 library tries to abstract away the gorier details of text processing in C, but in the process *grossly* misrepresents how the language works and winds up creating more confusion than it should.  Better to let students deal with the ugly side of C up front.  Better still, don't use C for an intro CS class.

Comment: @JohnBode in my university they taught C as our first language and it was fine. At first it was only the basic stuff, then simple pointers and structs, then linked lists and more complex data structures, and finally a bit of OS and networking stuff, all over the course of 4 semesters. However, aside from using valgrind and make, we had zero to very minimal talk about how to debug our code ourselves and when we had some random issue with no evident cause it was a bit rough.

Comment: @JohnBode I think as far as languages go C is still fine even for purely academical purposes, but if you're serious about teaching it you need to show beginners how they can get out of quicksand on their own with the right tools, or with concepts like unit tests that easily apply to anything else. Speaking of the ugly parts of C, there's also [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&pp=qAMBugMGCgJpdBAB) which actually makes sense, but avoiding C entirely in favor of C++ surely comes with its own set of problems.

Comment: @rdxdk: My program used C for the intro class too, and a third of my class *changed majors* citing C as the reason.  It is an *awful* teaching language.  So is C++.  So are Java and C#.  Python’s not perfect, but it’s a damn sight better than the others.